# Quelle est la différence entre "j'ai entendu dire" et "j'ai entendu parler" ?

Tags: lexique

Quelle est la différence entre *j'ai entendu dire* et *j'ai entendu parler* ? Donnez-moi quelques exemples, svp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La construction est la  première  des différences. La première locution verbale se construit toujours avec une complétive commençant par « que » alors que la seconde est toujours suivie de la préposition « de ».

- **entendre dire que** … — **entendre parler de** …

La seconde différence est dans le type d'information que l'on présente. Dans le cas de  « entendre dire » on fait état  du rapportage d'une information spécifique en cela qu'on doit utiliser un verbe ; dans le cas de « entendre parler »  on fait  état d'un rapportage à propos de quelque chose, sans dire quoi que ce soit de spécifique quant à ce rapportage.

> ([Internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/entendre-dire-que/)) **entendre dire que** , locution
> Percevoir une information indirectement
> (Traduction en anglais : to hear that)

- J'ai entendu dire qu'il existe une nouvelle littérature.
- J'ai entendu dire qu'il est champion de saut en hauteur.
- J'ai entendu dire que la pandémie approche de sa fin. *ou* J'ai entendu dire que la pandémie était proche de sa fin.

---

> ([Internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/20456/entendre-parler-de/))  **Entendre parler de**
> Signification Entendre ce que l'on dit sur une personne ou sur une chose, écouter les rumeurs.
> (Traduction en anglais : to hear about)

- J'entend beaucoup parler d'une nouvelle littérature, mais personne ne semble la trouver importante.
- J'ai entendu parler de ses succès sportifs.
- J'ai entendu parler du fait qu'il est champion de saut en hauteur.
- J'ai entendu parler de la fin de la pandémie. (*Cette fin peut être hypothétique.*)
- J'ai entendu parler de la fin prochaine de la pandémie.
- J'ai entendu parler du fait que la pandémie approche de sa fin.

Answer (score 1):

En dehors de ce qui a déjà été répondu sur ce qui suit ces verbes (*que* ou *de*), on peut aussi noter que *J'ai entendu parler* existe aussi en tant que phrase complète et avec un sens différent (*J'ai entendu quelqu'un parler*) alors *J'ai entendu dire* impose quasiment toujours une suite, mais ne change pas de sens si elle est omise.

Answer (score 0):

Les deux expressions veulent dire plus ou moins la même chose ; c'est une question de grammaire.

*J'ai entendu dire* doit être suivi de *que* + proposition subordonnée, par ex.

> J'ai entendu dire qu'il y aura un invité mystère.

*J'ai entendu parler* est suivi de *de* + nom, par ex.

> J'ai entendu parler d'un invité mystère.